# Delete item from JSON (PHP)

Tags: php, json

I reviewed a lot of post to delete an item from JSON with PHP but somehow the 'unset' function is not working anywhere in my code.
How can I delete 'SPEC_Info' from my JSON file with the code below I created to merge different JSON files (URLs)?

```
$sets = array();
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $json = substr($json, 1, -1);
    $sets = array_merge($sets, $data);
}

$new = json_encode($sets, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '<pre>';
echo $new;

$fp = fopen('dsales_watchjewel_combined_en.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $new);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: There is no call [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) in the posted code.

Comment: I removed as it had no function. But I had under '$json = substr($json, 1, -1);' the following: 'unset($json['SPEC_Info']);'

Comment: You copied the code from an answer. This makes the question misleading.

Comment: You are correct. I'll add the original code back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sets = array();
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $decoded = json_decode($json, true);
    oreach ($decoded as $key => $innerObject) { //based on the fact that your JSON contains multiple inner objects.
        if(isset($innerObject['SPEC_Info'])) {
            unset($decoded[$key]['SPEC_Info']);
        }
    }
    $sets[] = $decoded;
}
$new = json_encode($sets, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '<pre>';
echo $new;

$fp = fopen('combined.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $new);
close($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you. But it seems not to work. Here is an example of the JSON file: https://pastebin.com/GHMJKWEw

Comment: @ElyFornoville do you cannot remove `SPEC_Info`? Can you create file?

Comment: @ElyFornoville since your json contains multiple inner objects, you need to loop them and then remove the node you don't want.

Comment: @Auris thank you for the solutions. I tested it and it's not working + combining the JSON files also is not working anymore. I will try to get this working with your insights. I posted my full code in my question above.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP version 7.0

Comment: Ok, now I figured out what i was doing wrong, foreach values do not act as references of main array, so un-setting in a value does not unset in main array. I have updated my code. As for combining, please feel free to use what you used before

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thank you very much. I combined my code with yours and SPEC_Info is gone and also my combining works.

Comment: Happy I could help

Comment: @Auris I am trying to unset 2 or more items. I added thme next to eachother as ['SPEC_Bullet point 1 LIST']['SPEC_Bullet point 1 TEXT'] but that does not seem to work.

Comment: You will need to add the whole `if(isset($`... blocks for those 2 items, just like for `SPEC_Info`

Comment: @Auris found it. Again thank you for your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[`JSON`](http://json.org) is text. Also is the content of `$json`.

Evaluating the expression `$json['SPEC_Info']` triggers a warning (you cannot use string offsets in strings), converts `'SPEC_Info'` to a number (`0`) and accesses the first character of `$json`.

[`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) cannot be used with `$json['SPEC_Info']`. It doesn't make any sense.

[`JSON`](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. In order to use it you have to decode the JSON back into the original data structure. PHP provides the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for this purpose. Pass `TRUE` as its second argument to ask it to return arrays, not objects (they are easier to manipulate).

**This answers handles only the "why unset() doesn't work" part of the question. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48703608/4265352) provided by @Auris to find out how to handle the JSON properly.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code with combining my JSON files + removing multiple items.

```
$urls = array
( 'URL'
, 'URL'
);

$sets = array();
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach ($data as $key => $innerObject) { //based on the fact that your JSON contains multiple inner objects.
        if (isset(
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 1'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 2'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 3'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 4'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 5'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Extra info'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Keywords'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Featured'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 1 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 2 LIST'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet Point 1'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 2 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet Point 1 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet Point 2'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 3 LIST'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet Point 2 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 3 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 4 LIST'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 4 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet Point 3'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet Point 3 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 5 LIST'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 5 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet Point 4 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet Point 5'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet Point 5 TEXT'],
            $innerObject['SPEC_Bullet point 1 LIST']
        )) {
            unset(
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 1'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 2'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 3'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 4'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 5'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Extra info'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Keywords'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Featured'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 1 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 2 LIST'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet Point 1'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 2 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet Point 1 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet Point 2'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 3 LIST'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet Point 2 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 3 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 4 LIST'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 4 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet Point 3'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet Point 3 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 5 LIST'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 5 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet Point 4 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet Point 5'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet Point 5 TEXT'],
                $data[$key]['SPEC_Bullet point 1 LIST']
            );
        }
    }
    $json = substr($json, 1, -1);
    $sets = array_merge($sets, $data);
}

$new = json_encode($sets, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '<pre>';
echo $new;

$fp = fopen('combined.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $new);
fclose($fp);
```